# Using jpeglib with 16 bit grayscale picture

Tags: c++, compression, jpeg

I'm trying to use the jpeglib for a lossy 16bit grayscale compression. Working with real 16bit pictures is important for me, because the compressed pictures are for medical use.

Is a 16bit compression with one colorspace possible?

If yes:
What changes are necessary to do this?

Comment: And what is the question? Also consider not doing it. Diagnostic value of medical images may degrade when lossy compression is applied. Medical images are usually stored in lossless formats for that specific reason.

Comment: Congratulations. Sounds like you it works as intended.

Comment: @teroi:  JPEG2000 at least has a lossless mode.  I'd suggest the OP use it, then.

Comment: @JoeZ : I'm aware of that and lossless mode may be and is used for medical images. The question, however, was specifically about lossy compression.

Answer (score 3):

The original JPEG standard supports only 8 or 12 bits/sample for lossy compression, and 2 through 16 bits/sample for lossless compression. So the short answer is No, it is not possible to get 16 bits/sample with lossy JPEG compression.

The IJG JPEG library only supports lossy compression, so even switching to lossless compression would not be sufficient. You'd have to use a different library as well.

The IJG JPEG library does support 12 bits/sample, but only if you compile a special version of it. Refer to the install.txt/install.doc file.

There is a quasi-standard JPEG extension called JPEG-HDR that could be (ab)used to support a larger bit depth, but I don't know if it can support 16 bits/sample, and it's probably not a good solution anyway.